# How do I stop devices from using the Internet using arp spoofing?

Tags: arp-spoofing, arp

I have a virtual machine of Kali Linux and trying arp spoofing using the arpspoof tool I installed on Kali. I am trying to test out how I would stop devices from accessing the Internet.

I have tried spoofing the router's MAC address by using `arpspoof -i wlan0 -t (victim ip) (router ip)`.

I run `arp -a` on my victim machine and it works as expected (the router's IP is associated with my Kali's MAC address and when I ping the router on the victim machine it doesn't get any replies from the router.

HOWEVER, I can still use the internet. How is this possible? If I can't get any replies from the router shouldn't the internet not work?

(And yes... I am doing this on my own network)

Comment: Whenever troubleshooting network flows ***always*** run a packet capture so that you can see what's happening on the wire.

Comment: Did you flush the victim's ARP table?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not certain but I suspect an already established TCP connection no longer needs ARP. A better fit for your question would be here:https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *"but I suspect an already established TCP connection no longer needs ARP"*- it still needs to know which MAC address to send the data to. Some systems (like Linux) don't always do ARP requests to learn about the MAC address of the peer. If they receive a packet from the peer (which is the case for an established TCP connection unless it is idle) then they will update their ARP table based on the mapping between MAC and IP address from the received packet.

Comment: Oh I see.. So an already established TCP wouldn't be allowing the victim's device to access the internet?